# given rank of a string, find all substrings in a given string with the given rank

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

Suppose the rank pattern of a string is based on numbering the characters from 1 to k if there are k distinct characters in it
(there is an order provided on the characters used, here we assume A < B < C.... and so on for example, but generally it will be something which can be tell us char(X) < or = or > char(Y) in O|1| ) 
Then we follow with assigning the numbers to corresponding indices where the character occurs.

eg-

> string - C D B C B, here B - 1, C - 2, D - 3
>
> > rank   - 2 3 1 2 1   creating the corresponding rank array

eg 2 -

> string - D E G B C D  here B - 1, C - 2, D - 3, E - 4, G - 5
>
> > rank   - 3 5 4 1 2 3

(in short, we assign the smallest character to value 1, then next greater to 2, and so on )

Now, the question is this:

Given a string S of size m and rank pattern in form of array P of size n; find the no. of sub-strings of it which has the given rank pattern?
(m will be greater than n to make multiple possible solutions in a string S)

eg.-

> S is  A C B A D C A E
>
> > P is  1 3 2 1 4
> >         there are two substrings in S that conform to the pattern P
>
> here, in the substring [0, 4] i.e A C B A D
>
> > rank 1 3 2 1 4
>
> again in the substring [3, 7] i.e A D C A E
>
> > rank 1 3 2 1 4

so, the answer is 2 here..

I know of an O|SR| soln. and an O|S(logR + RlogR)| soln. 
Can we do better ?? If so, can someone tell me how??

Comment: Read this problem from here: http://cepc09.ii.uni.wroc.pl/accountant.pdf and its solution http://cepc09.ii.uni.wroc.pl/solutions.html